# Pasted content not being being read from the editor when paste event is occuring

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce, editor, paste

I'm using Tiny MCE5 to create a `PastePostProcess` event to be able to validate the contents in the text editor or using the Javascript `onpaste` function. The issue I have is that both paste functions are invoked after the content has been parsed from the clipboard but before it's added to the editor which means when validating the textbox it's not including the pasted content that was done. What's the best way to create a paste function **after** the content has been parsed from the clipboard and **after** the content has been included in the keyboard.